# Laravel 4.1 New user registration with email activation

Tags: email, laravel-4, registration

Please can some Laravel intellectual point me in the right direction. In the interests of DRY and using Laravels awesome helpers etc I want to know if anyone has a solution to this :
For registering a new user, all the examples and documentation I can find, seem to have a form which asks for email, username etc 
The input is verified (or not) and a user is created and added to db. Some examples go on to send a welcome email to the new user. I have an issue with this process as anyone can sign up using any email address even if it is not theirs. Hence my desire to incorporate an email with an activation link to ensure ownership of the address before user activation.

Am I missing something or does Laravel have some sort of token generating function that can assist in generating a token and/or emailing to a new user? I have setup password reminders and see there is an awesome method : Password::remind
which generates a token etc and sends an email to the user, and was wondering if there is such a thing I could use for activation email.

If not the only way I can see this being possible is to add 2 fields to the db (token and user_activated) then in controller when user is saved, gen a token somehow and save it and a value to the user_activated field. Then send out an email with a link to a controller which when clicked checks the token, matches the user and updates the user_activated field and logs the user on etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

Below I leave my old answer for old versions of Laravel, but, for laravel 5.2+, you just do:

```
php artisan make:auth

php artisan migrate
```

---

Here's a package I wrote for authenticating a user by email (includes resend confirmation and password reset):

You can see a demonstration here:

https://signup.edenwired.com/

Source code available here:

https://github.com/iateadonut/signup/

Naturally, if you're going to use these snippets in your own script rather than downloading my script, you should eliminate references to the namespace iateadonut/signup/

This is the login form (a blade template); if you are logged in, it gives you a link to log out; otherwise it gives you a login form:

```
@if ( Auth::guest() )

<form method='POST' action="{{ URL::to('/login') }}">
<label class='loginLabel'>email: </label>
<input name='email' id='email'> <br />
<label class='loginLabel'>password: </label>
<input type='password' name='pword' id='pword'> <br />
<label class='loginLabel'><span class='labelHolder'>.</span></label>

<input type=checkbox> Remember Me 
<input type=submit value='Log In' name='remember'>
</form>

    @if ( isset( $loginMessage ) )
    <p>{{ $loginMessage }}</p>
    @endif

<label class='loginLabel'><span class='labelHolder'>.</span></label>
<a href='signup'>Sign up / Reset Password</a>

@else

You are logged in.  {{ HTML::link('logout', 'Log out.') }}

@endif
```

This is the route for login and logout (/meat is the directory that an authenticated user would be redirected to).

If a user is not logged in, he is brought to the website root:

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

If the user goes to 'logout', first we check if he is logged in; if so, log him out; then, either way, return the user to the website root:

```
Route::get( 'logout', function(){
    if ( !Auth::guest() ) Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Login routine for www.webroot.com/login:

```
Route::get ('login', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

This is what is posted from the login form.  Notice that Auth::attempt also takes the argument Input::get('remember') - this is Laravel's built in function to remember the login.  If the login fails, we nest the loginForm (above) and give it an error message:

```
Route::post( 'login', function()
{
    $credentials = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('pword'),
            'id_code'   => '1'
    );

    if ( Auth::attempt($credentials, Input::get('remember')) )
    {
        return Redirect::to('/meat');
    } else {
        return View::make('signup::home')
            ->nest('loginForm', 'signup::loginForm')
            ->with('loginMessage', 'Invalid Login.');
    }

});
```

This is the sign up form; the one in the project includes password recovery and resend confirmation email, but we'll ignore those in this answer; also not included is javascript that confirms a valid email and checks that both passwords are the same.

In the source, there is also some jquery that connects to the database to make sure the email address the user wants is not already used:

```
<div class='signupbox'>

    <form action='signup2' method='post'>

    your email address: <br>
    <div id='EMAIL' style='float:right;'></div><input type='text' name='email' id='email2'><br>

    password: <br>
    <div id='PW1' style='float:right;'></div><input type=password maxlength=20 name='pw' id='pw' ><br>

    confirm password: <br>
    <div id='PW3' style='float:right;'></div><input type=password maxlength=20 name='pw2' id='pw2' ><br>

    <input type='submit' value='create account' disabled=true id='createAccount' class='createAccount'></form>

    <p>Use this when signing up for a new account.</p>

</div>
```

Here are two routes for signing up:

This just redirects the user to a signup form:

```
Route::get( 'signup', array( 'uses' => 'Iateadonut\Signup\SignupController@showSignup' ));
```

This one accepts the post of the signup form:

```
Route::post( 'signup2', array('uses' => 'Iateadonut\Signup\SignupController@signup2'));
```

The signup controller looks like this; first it generates a 25 character random string, then inputs that and the email address and hashed password into the database, then sends an email to the user so he can confirm that the email address is his:

```
public function signup2()
{

    //GENERATE $newcode - RANDOM STRING TO VERIFY SIGNUP
    for( $code_length = 25, $newcode = ''; strlen($newcode) < $code_length; $newcode .= chr(!rand(0, 2) ? rand(48, 57) : (!rand(0, 1) ? rand(65, 90) : rand(97, 122))));

    $user = new User;
    $user->email        = Input::get('email');
    $user->password     = Hash::make( Input::get('pw') );
    $user->id_code      = $newcode;
    $user->save();

    $data = array(
        'email'     => Input::get('email'),
        'clickUrl'  => URL::to('/') . '/confirm/' . $newcode
    );

    Mail::send('signup::emails.signup', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->to( Input::get('email') )->subject('Welcome!');
    });

    return View::make('signup::signup2')->with($data);

}
```

And the view for the email must contain a link with the id_code that was created (signup.blade.php in the views/emails directory):

```
Please click on:<br /><br />

{{ HTML::link( $clickUrl ) }} <br /><br />

to confirm your account.
```

And of course, to put this in a database, you'll need a table; here are some of the details of the migration (the field pw_code is for password recovery, which isn't discussed in this answer):

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->string('remember_token', 100);      
        $table->string('id_code')->default(0);
        $table->string('pw_code')->default(0);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here is the route that the confirmation email links to:

```
Route::get( 'confirm/{id_code}', array( 'uses' => 'Iateadonut\Signup\SignupController@confirm' ));
```

And the function confirm() in the signup controller looks like this:

```
public function confirm( $id_code )
{

    if ( $user_info = User::where('id_code', '=', $id_code)->first() )
    {

        $uid    = $user_info->id;
        $email  = $user_info->email;

        $data = array(
            'id_code'   => $id_code,
            'user_id'   => $uid,
            'email'     => $email
        );

        $user   = User::find($uid);
        $user->id_code = 1;
        $user->save();

        Auth::login( User::find($uid) );

        return View::make('signup::confirmed')->with($data);

    } else {

        return View::make('signup::confirmedError')->nest('loginForm', 'signup::loginForm');

    }

}
```

And last but not least, because you are sending passwords, you surely want to be using a secure connection; make sure you have something like this in filters.php:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
});
```

And I think that's it!  Laravel makes it very simple for you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can build this by your own or use for example this Package:
[cartalyst/sentry](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry)
.

They have this functionality built in.

EDIT

If you still want to have a solution just look at here:

https://github.com/BenBradleySmith/email-verification